# Generating random samples from a power law and testing them with R igraph

Tags: distributions, random-generation, power-law

I haven't looked into power laws before, so the question may very well have an obvious, embarrassing answer. In some ways it dovetails with [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/179623/67822).

The problem may be in the method, or in the interpretation of the `power.law.fit()` [function in the igraph r package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/igraph/versions/0.4.1/topics/power.law.fit).

I used the following [method from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomNumber.html) and also reflected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918827/4089351):

$$f(y)= [(x_1^{n+1}-x_0^{n+1})\,y+x_0^{n+1}]^{1/(n+1)}$$

where $x_0$ and $x_1$ come about from using inverse transform sampling to generate a power-law sample from a uniform distribution $f_X(x)=Cx^n, x\in [x_o,x_1].$ These values arise during the calculation of $C$ to makes sure that the pdf integrates to 1.

I'm plotting the results because the result does suggest a power law distribution on visual inspection:

```
x1 = 5           # Maximum value
x0 = 0.1         # Min value can't be zero; otherwise X^0^(neg) is 1/0.
alpha = -2.5     # It has to be negative.
y = runif(1e5)   # Number of samples
x = ((x1^(alpha+1) - x0^(alpha+1))*y + x0^(alpha+1))^(1/(alpha+1))
hist(x, prob = T, breaks=40, ylim=c(0,10), xlim=c(0,1.2), border=F, 
col="yellowgreen", main="Power law density")
lines(density(x), col="chocolate", lwd=1)
lines(density(x, adjust=2), lty="dotted", col="darkblue", lwd=2)
h = hist(x, prob=T, breaks=40, plot=F)
     plot(h$count, log="xy", type='l', lwd=1, lend=2, 
     xlab="", ylab="", main="Density in logarithmic scale")
```

[image]

Here is the summary of the data:

```
> summary(x)
   Min.   1st Qu.  Median    Mean   3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.1000  0.1208  0.1584    0.2590  0.2511   4.9388
```

---

The problem is in interpreting the results of applying `power.law.fit()` to the generated data in `x`. Aside from the fact that each time I run this function on `x` it takes from 5 to 10 minutes to return results, these return the minimum value, $0.1,$ and the alpha value, $-2.5$ without a glitch, yet they seem to indicate that the vector does not come from a power law distribution.

I have run the test for `set.seed(0)` through `set.seed(4)` with the following results:

```
1. set.seed(0); logLik 106703.4; KS.stat 0.005310278; KS.p 0.007109891; 
2. set.seed(1); logLik 106737.5; KS.stat 0.005025666; KS.p 0.01280314; 
3. set.seed(2); logLik 105858.9; KS.stat 0.005552832; KS.p 0.004218761; 
4. set.seed(3); logLik 107102.7; KS.stat 0.005953606; KS.p 0.001674007; 
5. set.seed(4); logLik 107004.3; KS.stat 0.00607452;  KS.p 0.001247162.
```

I presume that the key to interpret these results is according to [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/fit_power_law.html):

> **logLik**     Numeric scalar, the log-likelihood of the fitted parameters.
>
> **KS.stat**    Numeric scalar, the test statistic of a Kolmogorov-Smirnov
>   test that compares the fitted distribution with the input vector.
>   Smaller scores denote better fit.
>
> **KS.p**   Numeric scalar, the p-value of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.
>   Small p-values (less than 0.05) indicate that the test rejected the
>   hypothesis that the original data could have been drawn from the
>   fitted power-law distribution.

---

> THE QUESTION: Is there something incorrect, not power-law distributed, in the generated values, or am I misusing, or misinterpreting the testing with igraph?

Comment: With that sample size is it reasonable to expect it to fit any distribution you choose?

Comment: @mdewey shouldn't this be the more reason to get a high p value, suggesting that the sample could indeed come from a power law distribution?

Comment: I would have thought that a power law distribution (or at least a Pareto distribution) would not have a maximum value parameter. I might generate data with something like `xmin=0.1; alpha=2.5; y=runif(1e5); z=xmin/(1-y)^(1/alpha)`

Comment: @Henry That may very well be the problem. If you have time, take a look at [this Wolfram MathWorld post](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomNumber.html).